# Python Click Library Rename Argument

Tags: python, python-click

I am using the `Click` library but I can't seem to find a behavior similar to `dest` from `argparse`.

For example, I have

```
@click.option('--format', type=click.Choice(['t', 'j']))
def plug(format):
  pass
```

Notice that I am using a flag with `--format` that gets translated into a built-in Python construct `format` which is not ideal.

Is there a way to change the argument passed into the click function for options?

Comment: Just a meta-note here, you should be careful which tags you select to accompany your question.  This `click` tag has nothing to do with your question as it is referring to a mouse click.

Comment: Good point. removed :)

Comment: This newly introduced me to the python Click library which initially impressed me.  However, deeply reading through these docs, I've yet to find this simple (useful) functionality of argparse.  What a shame. :(

Comment: See http://click.pocoo.org/5/parameters/#parameter-names for the way to do this.

Answer (score 14):

Renaming an option to a differently named function argument is possible by decorating the function with

```python
@click.option('--format', '-f', 'format_arg_name')
def plug(format_arg_name):
    print(format_arg_name)
```

then it will remap the option named `format` and make it available as the `format_arg_name` parameter.

`format_arg_name` will not be available as a command line option, but `--format` and `-f` are.

Answer (score 11):

While `Click` doesn't have `dest`-equivalent of `argparse`, it has certain argument-naming behavior which can be exploited. Specifically, for parameters with multiple possible names, it will prefer non-dashed to dashed names, and as secondary preference will prioritize longer names over shorter names.

URL: http://click.pocoo.org/dev/parameters/#parameter-names

So if you declare your option as...

```
@click.option('--format', 'not-format', type=click.Choice(['t', 'j']))
```

...then Click will prioritize non-dashed variant (`'not-format'`) and call your function with `not_format=...` argument.

Of course it also means that this alternative spelling can also be used in command line. If that is not desired, then I guess you could add a decorator to rename keyword arguments:

```
import functools

def rename_kwargs(**replacements):
    def actual_decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
            for internal_arg, external_arg in replacements.iteritems():
                if external_arg in kwargs:
                    kwargs[internal_arg] = kwargs.pop(external_arg)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_func
    return actual_decorator
```

Testing code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    @rename_kwargs(different_arg='format')
    def tester(different_arg):
        print different_arg

    tester(format='test value')
```

Test output:

```
$ python test_decor.py
test value
```

In your case, it would look like:

```
@click.option('--format', type=click.Choice(['t', 'j']))
@replace_kwargs(not_format='format')
def plug(not_format):
    pass
```

Comment: The behaviour regarding "certain argument-naming behavior which can be exploited", is explicitly documented (though I didn't find it until a colleague pointed me towards it). http://click.pocoo.org/5/parameters/#parameter-names

Comment: looks to me like `return func(*args, **kwargs)` is one level too deep...